# Issue of Pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy

> Here is my data:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('gp_data.csv',sep= ";")
df2 = pd.read_csv('ms_data.csv',sep= ";")
#2.7.2
student_data = pd.concat([df1, df2])
#2.7.3 
df3 = pd.read_csv('gp_grades.csv',sep= ";")
df4 = pd.read_csv('ms_grades.csv',sep= ";")
#2.7.4
student_grades = pd.concat([df3, df4])
#2.7.5
student = pd.merge(left=student_grades, right=student_data, left_on='student_id', right_on='student_id')
```

> For a student to pass the exam, they have to score 12 or higher in one
> of their G1, G2, or G3 test. With this information, do the following:
>
> Select all the students who failed the exam. My codes are below:

```
crit_a1 = student.G1 = 12
crit_a2 = student.G2 = 12
crit_a3 = student.G3 = 12
final_crit_a != crit_a1 | crit_a2 | crit_a3
```

> NameError: name 'final_crit_a' is not defined
>
> Anyone can help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If need assign inverted chained masks use `~` and assign by `=`, for compare use `>=` for greater or equal:

```
crit_a1 = student.G1 >= 12
crit_a2 = student.G2 >= 12
crit_a3 = student.G3 >= 12
final_crit_a = ~(crit_a1 | crit_a2 | crit_a3)
```

If change logic - get all students with less like 12 values with chained by `&` for bitwise `AND`:

```
crit_a1 = student.G1 < 12
crit_a2 = student.G2 < 12
crit_a3 = student.G3 < 12
final_crit_a = (crit_a1 & crit_a2 & crit_a3)
```

What is same like compare all selected columns with [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for test at least one `True` or by [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for test if all values are `True`s per rows:

```
final_crit_a = ~((student[['G1','G2','G3']] >= 12).any(axis=1))
```

---

```
final_crit_a = (student[['G1','G2','G3']] < 12).all(axis=1)
```